# I keep having issues with setting multiple layouts in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, layout, next.js13

[image]

The current folder structure is like this:

I want to use a different layout only on the register page.

According to the official document, if you want to apply different multiple layouts, you need to create layout.tsx for each page.

So I'm trying to apply it like that

You are mounting a new body component when a previous one has not first unmounted. It is an error to render more than one body component at a time and attributes and children of these components will likely fail in unpredictable ways. Please only render a single instance of  and if you need to mount a new one, ensure any previous ones have unmounted first.
at body

with this error

Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

This error appears.

After searching, it was said that the body and html should not overlap, so I changed the code in the layout.tsx folder in the register folder like this

```js
import "../globals.css";

import ContentCard from "@/components/Card/ContentCard";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return <ContentCard>{children}</ContentCard>;
}
```

This brings up the header component in the main layout.tsx.

It wasn't even loaded from register layout.tsx.

How should I solve it?

Looking at the official documentation, no matter how much I change these settings, it doesn't apply. help..

Answer (score 2):

In Next.js 13 app directory, a root layout is required and shared among all the children pages. So if you create a layout.tsx inside app dir that count as a root layout and root layout should contain html and body tag. and then if you create page level layout.tsx then it will be nested layout and will be shared across all pages in that segment. So root layout will always there as parent.

Now in your case I think you want multiple root layout.So, you need to group routes. I think next doc has nice visualization to understand how route grouping works. See here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts

So you need to group your route to show diff root layout.
Don't forget to include html and body tag in your root layout(in your case maybe two different root layout).

For reference

1. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts
2. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups

Comment: So if I put body and html tags in each layout.tsx

You are mounting a new body component when a previous one has not first unmounted. It is an error to render more than one body component at a time and attributes and children of these components will likely fail in unpredictable ways. Please only render a single instance of and if you need to mount a new one, ensure any previous ones have unmounted first. at body

this error comes out

If I want to separate the layout, isn't it correct to redefine html and body for each layout file?

Comment: You only include html and body tag in your root layout, not in nested layout. Cause only segmented page will inherit the layout. there is no chance to render duplication of body tag in two different root layout, cause they will not mixed up. At a time only one root layout will load.

Comment: import "../globals.css";
import Header from "@/components/Header/Header";
import ContentCard from "@/components/Card/ContentCard";
import Providers from "@/redux/Providers";

export default function RegisterLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Providers>
        <ContentCard>{children}</ContentCard>
      </Providers>
    </>
  );
}


However, as I wrote in the article, if I write in this way, the Header component only in the root layout.tsx appears on the register page.

Answer (score 1):

It has simple solution. Just use `<html>` and `<body>` tags in your **RootLayout**. But don't use `<html>` and `<body>` tags in your **nested layouts**.

So, your `app/layout.tsx` should be like this:

```
import "../globals.css";

    import ContentCard from "@/components/Card/ContentCard";

    export default function RootLayout({
      children,
    }: {
      children: React.ReactNode;
    }) {
        return
        <html>
            < body >
                <ContentCard />
                {children} 
            </body>
        </html>
    }
```